# How to set the Image property of a PictureBox Control by using OpenFileDialog? C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

How to set the Image property of a PictureBox Control by using OpenFileDialog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set [`PictureBox.Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image.aspx) using [`Image.FromFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx)

```
OpenFileDialog _openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
_openFileDialog.FileOk += OpenFileDialogFileOk;
_openFileDialog.CheckFileExists = true;
_openFileDialog.CheckPathExists = true;
_openFileDialog.ShowDialog();

void OpenFileDialogFileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var imageInformation = new FileInfo(_openFileDialog.FileName);
    var sizeInBytes = imageInformation.Length;

    myPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(_openFileDialog.FileName);
}
```

Comment: Yes it works! Thanks sir.. How if I want to check the file size of the image?

Comment: @yonan2236, I've added that aswell. This will get you the file size of the image in Bytes. Remember that you need to ensure that it's the correct MIME-type before you add it to the picturebox, otherwise you might get a "out of memory exception".