# C# Winforms FileInfo Error

Tags: c#, winforms

I used the code from this question [How to set the Image property of a PictureBox Control by using OpenFileDialog? C# winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767226/how-to-set-the-image-property-of-a-picturebox-control-by-using-openfiledialog-c) to open an image using OpenFileDialog, however at this part of the code `var imageInformation = new FileInfo(openFileDialog1.FileName);` i get an error: The type or namespace FileInfo could not be found. Why is that?

Comment: Missing a reference / using to System.IO ? Please refer to [FileInfo Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What reference do I need?

Comment: Check that you have included the namespace System.IO. ' using System.IO; ' at the top.

Comment: The FileInfo class belongs to the namespace System.IO. You need to add _using System.IO;_ to the list of namespaces used by your program (or write the full namespace: _System.IO.FileInfo imageInformation = new System.IO.FileInfo(....)_

Comment: Added it and now it works thanks for the help !

Comment: Better add the exact error next time (you can right click the compiler error and copy it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this reference:

using System.IO;